# How Should I pass a secret variable in the .tf file

Tags: terraform

HI I am trying to create a storage blob container in which the source uri = the SAS key key generated referring to the other storage account. It is working fine but i have to pass the SAS key as secret ( in azure portal)

I tried giving the SAS key directly, it is working but i need to pass the SAS key as secret

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TF_VAR_sas_token` as a pipeline variable with secret type.

When you perform a `terraform plan` and then `terraform apply`, please specify the values of the variables using the `-var` flag.

Please refer to [link](https://gaunacode.com/terraform-input-variables-using-azure-devops) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to save your SAS token in Azure Keyvault and link it to variable group. Authorize your pipeline to use the variable group.

Under your variables section: use

```
variables:
  - group: devgroupname
```

and use your secret name in script like this.

```
- task: Bash@3
            displayName: 'Terraform Init'
            env:
              ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
              ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
              ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
              ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                terraform init \
                  -backend-config="access_key=$(tf-az-sa-key1)"
              workingDirectory: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(FILE_PATH)"
```